# ReactJS forms, autofill login / password inputs

Tags: reactjs

When I'm rendering HTML from on server side (with JSP or another server-side technology) browser suggests me to save login / password inputs.

When I'm using ReactJS to render form I don't those suggestions from browser.

Is there any way to get form autofilling?

There is example of my form from ReactJS code

```
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="registration-block">
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <div className="registration-block-inputs">
                        <div className="input-block" id="input-block-0">
                            <div className="input-block-header">E-mail</div>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="login" id="login"
                                   value={this.state.login}
                                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                        </div>

                        {passwordInput}

                        <SubmitButton buttonName={this.props.buttonName} processing={this.state.processing}/>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            {popup}
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `type="password"` or `type="email"` HTML attributes so that the browser can determine the kind of information the input is accepting.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

All the form attributes are set by putting certain attributes on the actual html elements. You use certain elements based on what you want the browser to recommend. On top of that different browsers might use different attributes are various things. I would recommend this resource.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me... I tried attributes from this article but with no result. Browser does neither save nor suggest login/password

Comment: Which element are you putting it on ?